# Как передать значение в textarea без submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть веточка комментариев. Необходимо передать имя пользователя, которое заключено в теги `<p>` в textarea с динамическим id. Подскажите как это можно реализовать и как на примере это может выглядеть?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я думаю ответ зависит от того, что вы имеете. Например если **textarea** имеет атрибут **name**, то можно найти его с помощью функции **getElementsByName**.  Она вернет все элементы с заданным именем. В нашем примере оно уникально, поэтому выбираем первый элемент, меняем его значение и все.

На `<p>` вешаем **onclick** c функцией **insertNick**.  В параметре передаем текст тега. **this** это сам тег. **textContent** вернет текст который содержится внутри тега. Если в `<p>` будут и другие теги, вернет весь содержащийся в них текст, за вычитом тегов.

```
<script>
  function insertNick(nick) {

    var container = document.getElementsByName("entity")[0];

    container.value += nick;
  }

</script>


<p onclick="insertNick(this.textContent);">
  UserName
</p>


<form>
  <textarea name="entity"></textarea>
</form>
```

Или можно отыскать форму в которой находится **textarea**, получить **textarea** если знаем ее расположение.Т.е есть форма, нужный элемент в ней идет второй. Значит нужный элемент с индексом один.

```
<script>
  function insertNick(nick) {

    var form = document.getElementById("entity");

    form.elements[1].value += nick;
  }

</script>


<p onclick="insertNick(this.textContent);">
  UserName
</p>

<form id="entity">
  <input type="text" value="Дата">
  <br>
  <textarea> Ваш ник: </textarea>
</form>
```

Или можно получить форму, и отыскать нужный **textarea** по атрибуту **name**.

```
// получили форму. Получаем элемет формы с именем entity
var elem = form.elements.entity;
```

P.S. В JS я не эксперт, но данную проблему решал бы как-то так.